# Как сделать ячейки(разделители) в таблице?

Tags: java, таблицы

Всем привет! Есть некая задача по выводу таблицы умножения, пока не могу справиться  с разделителями между ячейками и столбцами, пример как должно будет выглядеть:

```
   |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
--+---+---+---+---+---+
  1|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
---+---+---+---+---+---+
  2|  2|  4|  6|  8| 10|
---+---+---+---+---+---+
  3|  3|  6|  9| 12| 15|
---+---+---+---+---+---+
  4|  4|  8| 12| 16| 20|
---+---+---+---+---+---+
  5|  5| 10| 15| 20| 25|
```

На данном этапе у меня выглядит так:

```
   |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
---+---+---+---+---+---+
  1|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
  2|  2|  4|  6|  8| 10|
  3|  3|  6|  9| 12| 15|
  4|  4|  8| 12| 16| 20|
  5|  5| 10| 15| 20| 25|
```

Код программы прилагаю

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final int tableNum = 5;

        System.out.print("   |");
        for(int a = 1; a <= tableNum; a++){
            System.out.print(space(a) + "|");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("---+");


        for(int a = 1; a <= tableNum; a++)
            System.out.print("---+");
        System.out.println();

        for(int a = 1; a <= tableNum; a++)
        {

            System.out.print(space(a) + "|");
            for(int b = 1; b <= tableNum; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(space(a * b) + "|");
            }

            System.out.println();


        }
    }

    public static String space(int y)
    {
        String str = new String();
        if(y < 10) str = "  " + y;
        else if(y < 100) str = " " + y;
        else str = "" + y;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
for(int b=1; b<=tableNum; b++) {
....
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
System.out.println();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше как-то так... Подстроит длину ваших разделителей под любую таблицу

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int tableNum = 100;

        final int countDelimeter = numbLength(tableNum*tableNum); 
        StringBuilder delimiterLine = createDelimiterLine(tableNum, countDelimeter);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableNum; i++) 
            sb.append(createLine(tableNum,i,countDelimeter)).append("\r\n").append(delimiterLine).append("\r\n");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    private static String createLine(final int tableNum, final int multiplier, final int countDelimeter) {
        final int x = multiplier==0 ? 1 : multiplier;
        return IntStream.range(1, tableNum+1).boxed()
            .map(i->createNumb(i*x, countDelimeter, ""))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("|", createNumb(x,countDelimeter,"|"), "|"));
    }

    private static StringBuilder createDelimiterLine(final int tableNum, final int countDelimeter){
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableNum+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < countDelimeter; j++) sb.append("-");
            sb.append("+");
        }
        return sb;
    }

    private static String createNumb (final int numb, final int countOfSpace, final String delemiter){
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfSpace-numbLength(numb); i++) sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(numb).append(delemiter);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static int numbLength (int number){
        return (int)(Math.log10(number) + 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код не идеален, но свою задачу выполняет. В переменной size можно указать размер таблицы. 
Например 10 выведет таблицу умножения вплоть до 10 * 10;

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int size = 5;
        int maxColWidth = ((size * size) + "|").length();

        String oneCellDivider = String.format("%" + maxColWidth + "s", "+").replace(" ", "-");
        String fullHorizontalDivider = String.format("%" + size + "s", "").replace(" ", oneCellDivider);

        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
            for(int k = 1; k <= size; k++){
                String value = k * i + "|";
                String result = String.format("%" + maxColWidth + "s", value);
                System.out.print(result);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            if(i != size) {
                System.out.println(fullHorizontalDivider);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
 1| 2| 3| 4| 5|
--+--+--+--+--+
 2| 4| 6| 8|10|
--+--+--+--+--+
 3| 6| 9|12|15|
--+--+--+--+--+
 4| 8|12|16|20|
--+--+--+--+--+
 5|10|15|20|25|
```